# Labels Numbering Chapter.NR

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, labels

What I am trying to do Is to have more precise Labels next to my equations which I reference later. Currently, all I get is (1),(2), usw. what I would like to have is (1.1) for the first label in the first chapter, and (2.1) for the first label in the second chapter. always starting with one, so the reader knows in which chapter to look for it.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This should perhaps be a comment but it is too long for that.

I do not know what you have done. In the `report` class equations are numbered per chapter. Try running this:

```
% eqnoprob.tex  SE 633257
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\section{Primo}

\begin{equation}
  a + b = c    \label{feq}
\end{equation}

Above equation is \ref{feq}.
\chapter{Second}

\section{Primo}

\begin{equation}
  a + b = c    \label{seq}
\end{equation}

Above equation is \ref{seq}.
\end{document}
```

You will see that the two equations are numbered `(1.1)` in the first chapter and `(2.1)` in the second.

Please edit your question by providing an MWE similar to the above that we can compile that shows your problem. Also in your edited/extended question please indicate what you have changed/added.